# How can I test for negative zero?

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point

Initially I thought `Math.Sign` would be the proper way to go but after running a test it seems that it treats `-0.0` and `+0.0` the same.

Comment: What is *negative zero* and how is it different than *positive zero* and how is it different than *zero*? Mathematically their are the same. *IEEE 754ically* maybe not.

Comment: Bitwise, how does the representation of -0.0 differ from +0.0? 0x800000 and 0x000000?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, have you ever attended a mathematical analysis course? :P

Comment: @klez, yes I have. I even have a degree in mathematics :-)

Comment: Mathematically you may know from which side of zero you approached it, computationally you may not. Nice to know sometimes.

Comment: For a complete question, please define *negative zero*.  For us doubters, you may have to prove that it actually exists.  As soon as you prove it exists, you'll have code that tests for it.

Comment: @abelenky: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_zero

Comment: If you're talking about IEEE doubles, [it is well defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero#Representations).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Here's a grotty hack way of doing it:

```
private static readonly long NegativeZeroBits =
    BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(-0.0);

public static bool IsNegativeZero(double x)
{
    return BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(x) == NegativeZeroBits;
}
```

Basically that's testing for the exact bit pattern of -0.0, but without having to hardcode it.

Comment: It seems your solution is about 25 times faster than mine.

Comment: As an added bonus, no additional overhead :)  You have to love the power of `unsafe` code sometimes :)

Comment: @leppie - Now this is awesome: `return *(((long*) &value));`

Comment: It's not really grotty, because (a) it is well encapsulated and (b) if the user can't rely on IEEE floating point,  then she can't rely on -0.0 even existing.  A better abstraction would be `bool IsNegative(double x){return BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(x) < 0;}`.  That's a function which should actually be in the standard `Math` class.

Comment: I saw this referred to in another answer and wondered why it's not in MiscUtil. But if you say its grotty...

Comment: @StephenKennedy: It's mostly not there because I've never had a reason to need it myself.

Comment: Just wanted to add a friendly remainder that this works for binary floating point (which is the case here), but not for decimal floating point (which allows for multiple representations of +/-0).

Answer (score 17):

After a bit of searching I finally made it to [Section 7.7.2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373) of the C# specification and came up with this solution.

```
private static bool IsNegativeZero(double x)
{
    return x == 0.0 && double.IsNegativeInfinity(1.0 / x);
}
```

Comment: While I applaud the ingenuity, I'm not sure it's the most *readable* approach :)

Comment: If you change the 1.0 to double.Epsilon, I think it *may* be okay though :)

Comment: @Jon - I added a check for zero.

Comment: Curious that 1 / double.Epsilon would evaluate to infinity.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram, not really.  double.Epsilon is denormalized, so it is smaller than 2**(min exponent).  There is no equivalent of denormalization for extremely *large* values, so the reciprocal is too large to be representable.

Answer (score 9):

Negative zero has the sign bit set.  Thus:

```
    public static bool IsNegativeZero(double value) {
        if (value != 0) return false;
        int index = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? 7 : 0;
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(value)[index] == 0x80;
    }
```

Edit: as the OP pointed out, this doesn't work in Release mode.  The x86 JIT optimizer takes the if() statement seriously and loads zero directly rather than loading *value*.  Which is indeed more performant.  But that causes the negative zero to be lost.  The code needs to be de-tuned to prevent this:

```
    public static bool IsNegativeZero(double value) {
        int index = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? 7 : 0;
        if (BitConverter.GetBytes(value)[index] != 0x80) return false;
        return value == 0;
    }
```

This is quite typical behavior for the x86 jitter btw, it doesn't handle corner cases really well when it optimizes floating point code.  The x64 jitter is much better in that respect.  Although there's arguably no worse corner case than giving meaning to negative zero.  Be forewarned.

Comment: For some reason, when I build this with a target of x86 with optimizations enabled and run it outside of Visual Studio passing `-0.0` will return `false`. Oh and this seems to be the middle ground performance wise.

Comment: I repro, the if statement confuzzles the JIT optimizer.  It now assumes the value equals zero, not negative zero and loads it directly with fldz rather than loading *value*.  Because that's quicker.  You are going to fight this badly in your own code as well.  Post updated.

Comment: Unfortunately to fully implement the ECMAScript standard I must be aware of `-0.0`.

Comment: I'm seeing standards collide head-on.  Good luck with it.

Answer (score 9):

```
x == 0 && 1 / x < 0
```

Comment: Integers do not have distinct positive zero and negative zero.

Answer (score 8):

Here's another hack. It takes advantage of the fact that `Equals` on a `struct` will do a bitwise comparison instead of calling `Equals` on its members:

```
struct Negative0
{
    double val;
    public static bool Equals(double d)
    {
        return new Negative0 { val = -0d }.Equals(new Negative0 { val = d });
    }
}
```

`Negative0.Equals(0); // false`
`Negative0.Equals(-0.0); // true`

Comment: `ValueType.Equals` not always performs a bitwise comparison. And, unfortunately, exact conditions when it chooses to do so are undocumented, and may vary between CLR versions/platforms.

Answer (score 3):

More generally, you can do,

```
bool IsNegative(double value)
{
    const ulong SignBit = 0x8000000000000000;
    return ((ulong)BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(value) & SignBit) == SignBit;
}
```

---

or alternatively, if you prefer,

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
private struct DoubleULong
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public double Double;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public readonly ulong ULong;
}

bool IsNegative(double value)
{
    var du = new DoubleULong { Double = value };
    return ((du.ULong >> 62) & 2) == 2;
}
```

The later gives an approximate 50% performance improvment in debug but. Once compiled in release mode and run from the command line **there is no significant difference**.

I couldn't generate a performance improvement using unsafe code either but this may be due to my inexperience.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm a bit baffled that after sitting here for more than 13 years (at the time of writing), this question has all these excellent (and somewhat elaborate) answers but not the most "straightforward" (IMO) one:*

```
static bool IsNegativeZero(double d) => Double.IsNegative(d) && d == 0.0;
```

Note that, according to the IEEE spec, -0.0 compares equal to +0.0, so there's no need to write `d == -0.0` although that will also work.