# Memory allocation clarification

Tags: c#

I am trying to set a negative zero to an array in two ways. I need to know how the memory will be allocated for each type.

Type 1:

```
double dArray=new double[2];
dArray[0]= 0;
dArray[1]=-0;
```

Type 2:

```
double dArray=new double[2];
dArray[0]=0;
dArray[1]=-dArray[0];
```

Can any one clarify on this.

Thanks,
Lokesh.

Comment: In both cases, you allocate memory in exactly the same manner. The only difference I see is the assignment. But, it's syntactic sugar as the effect and result are the same. I wouldn't assume compiler to be such a dumb machine to not to recognize it.

Comment: How the memory will be allocated? You are calling `new double[2]` two times. It would be rather obvious what would be allocated. Simply two arrays of doubles.

Comment: @Ash Yes, `-0` is a valid number in IEEE754 floating point.

Comment: There's positive and negative infinity. There is no such thing as negative 0 in `double` types in .NET.

Comment: The array/memory and the negative zero have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @David: But it is equivalent to `0`...

Comment: @Steven Who said anything about null? There's no such thing as null in `double`.

Comment: @David - Thanks, I didn't know that. Could you tell me when -0 does not equal 0.

Comment: The framework will allocate the memory. For managed types thats all you need to know. Just keep the scope as local as possible.

Comment: @Daniel `-0 == 0` in IEEE754, but they are distinct values.

Comment: @David: Typo, I meant 0 ofcourse. Fixed.

Comment: @David: Sounds kinda useless to me. Is there any real scenario that uses or needs this distinction?

Comment: @Daniel Have a look here for some discussion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_zero

Comment: `double zero=0;`
`double a=1/zero;//+infinity`
`double b=1/(-zero);//-infinity`

Comment: I assume one scenario where it is useful is arithmetic underflow. small positive numbers underflow to +0, small negative numbers to -0. Then if you divide by such an underflowed number you get the correct infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code doesn't compile. I think you mean

```
double[] dArray=new double[2];
```

A `double` is a value type and it makes no difference to its storage how you assign to a `double` value.  The two code samples (once fixed), result in exactly the same memory layout for `dArray`.

It would be very much clearer to always write `-0.0`.

Note that Visual Studio always represents negative zero as `0.0` which does tend to shake your confidence in the existence of `-0.0`!

There is some relevant discussion of negative zero here: [How can I test for negative zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739795/how-can-i-test-for-negative-zero)

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested in understanding your use case because ordinarily −0 = +0 = 0.

In any case they would both be treated as value types.