# How to get - 0 for round off small negative number?

Tags: c#, rounding

When I round off a small negative number it is rounded off to 0.
E.g: `decimal.Round(-0.001M, 2)` returns 0.

How can I get the sign if its rounded of to zero. Is there any other better way than to check `n<0` then do the round off?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi this seems to be for `decimal`, not `double`

Comment: @harold, shouldn't [Vladimir Reshetnikov's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10843285/464709) still apply?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: doesn't that answer fails if x == 0? And than really 0?

Comment: @Stefan, I don't think so because it actually tests for that case. My understanding is that dividing `1` by negative zero will produce negative infinity, which is less than zero.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I get a divide by zero exception when I test @Vladimir's answer and more over `Math.Round` or `Decimal.Round` returns a 0 without a sign hence i cannot check on the end result. Rather I can try only Sign(x) then do Math.Round(x)

Comment: @Bharath, okay, it looks like decimals are indeed worth another question then. I'll retract my close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing the bits works for decimal also. Thanks to @JonSkeet, else I'd have never known this trick.

```
var d = decimal.Round(-0.001M, 2);
bool isNegativeZero = d == decimal.Zero && decimal.GetBits(d).Last() < 0;
```

Here is the [Demo](http://ideone.com/noonz5)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other better way than to check n<0 then do the round off?

The simple answer is "no". That is the most straightforward way of doing it. Unless you have a good reason to write code any more complicated than that (that you haven't mentioned in the question), don't do it. You (or another developer) will eventually come back to this code after days or months and wonder why the code was written that way.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with your answer. Sorry I am accepting @Sriram Sakthivel's answer for the tweak he has done.