# C# Dependency Property Value Changed callback not firing when changing from zero to negative zero

Tags: c#, dependency-properties

I have a DependencyProperty of type double. Zero and negative zero are both different and valid values for the property. I have some logic that executes when the value changes.

Unfortunately, since negative zero and zero are considered 'equal' in C#, when the current value of the DependencyProperty is zero and I set negative zero, the value is updated but the Value Changed callbacks are not executed.

Is there some smart way I'm missing to force the ValueChanged callback to execute on new value? I can manually call UpdateSource/Target, but I don't own one of the objects that is binding to this property so I can't do it in all cases.

Comment: [How can I test for negative zero?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4739795)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am aware of how to detect it, but that doesn't help with a binding. This is under the hood!

Comment: Then it seems to me like you need a type that implements IEquatable and/or IComparable behavior in the way that you want.

Comment: @RobertHarvey One option is to wrap the value in a struct, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Can you store a mathematical transformation of the value, for instance `1/x`, and do the inversions in the getter and setter?  That converts 0 and -0 to Infinity and NegativeInfinity.  (Of course, if you also need +-Infinity as possible values, that doesn't work.)  Update: no, [not in the setter & getter](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html).