# How can I get the sign-bit of a double?

Tags: c#, double, std

What is the C# equivalent for C++

```
bool std::signbit( double arg );
```

The C++ reference description of this function is as follows:
Determines if the given floating point number arg is negative.
This function detects the sign bit of zeroes, infinities, and NaNs. Along with std::copysign, this macro is one of the only two portable ways to examine the sign of a NaN.

```
signbit(+0.0) = false
signbit(-0.0) = true
```

Comment: Not a complete equivalent, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4739869/1430156) may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure whether there is a builtin, but this should work:

```
private static readonly long SignMask = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(-0.0) ^
    BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(+0.0);

public static bool signbit(double arg)
{
    return (BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(arg) & SignMask) == SignMask;
}
```

Based on [this answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4739869).

Answer (score 3):

Reverse-engineered from the machine code in the Microsoft CRT, keeping it fast:

```
    public unsafe static bool stdsign(double d) {
        ushort* pd = (ushort*)&d;
        return (pd[3] & 0x8000) != 0;
    }
```

Passes all the tests that I know how to throw at it.  Little-endian architecture assumed.

Comment: +1, Though I prefer staying clear of `unsafe` code. (I doubt mine is any less efficient.)

Comment: I'm a bit dismayed at the strangeness of the Intel code.  No idea why they did it this way.

Comment: Yes. If they really have to go this way, why didn't they use either `ulong*` or `byte*`...

Comment: Well, ulong* is expensive for 32-bit code.  The only reasonable guess I have is that this code came from the 16-bit processor days.

Comment: If you've reached the point where you are examining the bitfield of your NaNs to trace the providence of your numbers (rather than higher level approaches like exceptions or flags), your code is low-level enough to justify parts of it being `unsafe`.  The sign-bit of zeroes can be detected with arithmetic operations (1/+0.0 vs 1/-0.0) and the sign bit of infinities can be detected trivially (e.g., via  via `Double.IsPositiveInfinity`), but NaN's sign bit can only be detected by inspecting the bit.  Not IMO idiomatic C#, but possibly necessary if interacting with other code.