# Why is zero assumed as a positive number when it is divisor?

Tags: c#, math

Please check the following code.

```
double zero1 = 0;
double zero2 = -zero1;
bool test = zero1 == zero2;    // true                       (1)

double number1 = 3 / zero1;    // positive infinity          (2)
double number2 = 3 / zero2;    // negative infinity          (3)
```

How can we explain this contradiction? As far as I can think of

1) It is assumed as some positive small number (like `double.Epsilon`) when it is divisor. But this is contradicting `statement (3)` as `zero2` equals zero (and should be assumed as positive small number also) also.

2) It is always assumed as some positive small number. This is contradicting statement (1) (if `zero1` is positive, then `zero2` should be negative)

3) Or maybe division is not safe. Sometimes `3/0` might give me negative infinity also.

What is the correct approach, explanation?

Comment: Where's the contradiction? Your title seems to contradict your final line, but that's the only contradiction I see...

Comment: It preserves the rule that sign(x / y) = (sign(x) xor sign(y))

Comment: I think the perceived contradiction is that even this is true `-0 == +0` this is not true: `3/-0 == 3/+0`

Comment: @JonSkeet statement1, statement2 and statement3 contradicts.

Comment: Again, I don't see the contradiction. It matches with JLS 15.21.1: "Positive zero and negative zero are considered equal." - just don't assume that x == y implies z / x == z / y.

Comment: Whoops - hadn't noticed that this is C# rather than Java, and don't have the C# spec to hand, but I'm 99.99% sure you'll find something similar there. There are lots of things like this in floating point.

Comment: @JonSkeet Himm ok. Then how can I know if a zero is a positive zero or a negative zero? Dividing a number with it and check if the result positive?

Comment: Use `Math.Sign` perhaps?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

Comment: @JonSkeet `Math.Sign(-0)` returning 0.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, worth reading

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. Then using division would be reasonable, I think. Or using `BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits`, possibly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Double` type has distinct values for positive zero and negative zero.

When you compare a positive zero to a negative zero, they are equal. Zero is equal to zero regardless of the sign.

A zero is exactly zero, it's not a very small value. A positive zero and a negative zero have the same exact value eventhough they have different signs. If you compare a very small positive value to a very small negative value, they are not equal.

When you divide something with zero you get positive or negative infinity depending on the signs of the operands. AFAIK, this is the only operation where the sign of the zero gives a different result. Using `Math.Sign` on a negative zero for example returns a positive zero.

Comment: Thank you Guffa. How can I know if a zero is positive or negative? Dividing a number with it and check if the result positive? Or any other clear way?

Comment: @serdar, does it matter? Just check `IsInfinity` instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isinfinity.aspx

Comment: @serdar: There are some ways to check for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739795/how-can-i-test-for-negative-zero

Answer (score 0):

If you really care, you can do this,

```
bool IsPositive(double value)
{
    const ulong SignBit = 0x8000000000000000;
    return ((ulong)BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(value) & SignBit) != SignBit;
}
```

Comment: This is an answer to the comment I think. Thank you