# object value got using reflection, BitConverter gives weird result

Tags: c#

So I get a value as

```
var info = item.GetType().GetProperty(p.Key);
var value = info.GetValue(item);
```

`value` is double and is equal to 0, i.e. value.GetType().Name is "Double" and (double)value == 0 is true

But when I do BitConverter.GetBytes((double)value) I get

```
[0]: 0
[1]: 0
[2]: 0
[3]: 0
[4]: 0
[5]: 0
[6]: 0
[7]: 128
```

128 ??? What is that 128 doing in here? How do I get all 0 as it should be?

Comment: IEEE 754 floating point numbers have two representations of 0: +0 and -0. You will see `BitConverter.GetBytes(-0.0)` produces the same layout.

Comment: @Romoku i see that's an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is that 128 doing in here?

For the first part of the question: IEEE 754 floating point numbers define zero equality to mean that 0 can be either positive or negative. However, the storage layout for +0 and -0 is different.

> How do I get all 0 as it should be?

If the code will be producing values of -0, it needs to serialize the storage layout, and +0 and -0 need to be normalized then the best route is to check the value of the double before calling the `BitConverter.GetBytes(double)`.

There are several methods mentioned in [How can I test for negative zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739795/how-can-i-test-for-negative-zero).

In the simple case assume 0 should be +0:

```
var info = item.GetType().GetProperty(p.Key);
var value = info.GetValue(item);
var normalized = (double) value;

if (normalized == 0.0)
{
    normalized = 0.0;
}

var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(normalized);
```