# C# is printing float value of -0.0 wrong

Tags: c#, printing, floating-point, format

```
Console.WriteLine(" 0.0 float: 0x00000000, {0}", (float)0x00000000);
Console.WriteLine("-0.0 float: 0x80000000, {0}", (float)0x80000000);
```

C# prints 0.0 for the first one, and instead of -0.0 prints 2.147484E+09 which is not what I expected. *According to this online IEEE-754 floating-point format converter 0x80000000 should be a -0.0, since floating-point format uses sign-magnitude format, which supports -0.0.*

https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

How do we get C# to print -0.0 for UInt32 bit pattern of 0x80000000?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I test for negative zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739795/how-can-i-test-for-negative-zero)

Comment: Your cast does not **reinterpret** the bits of 0x80000000 **as a float**, it simply **converts** the integer value to a float with the same value (but completely different bit representation). In C#, to reinterpret , you need to use BitConverter.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `(float)0x80000000` you are taking an integer value (0x80000000 = 2.147484E+09) and casting it to float (the value is the same, but now it's a float). What you want is take the byte array and interpret it as float:

```
uint l = (uint)0x80000000;
float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(l), 0);
Console.WriteLine("-0.0 float: 0x80000000, {0}", f);
```

Output:

```
-0.0 float: 0x80000000, 0
```

Comment: Ah, I see. C# behavior is a bit different from C++. How do we get the correct value of -0.0?

Comment: Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", BitConverter.GetBytes(-0.0)));
Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: What I'm after is converting the UInt32 pattern of 0x80000000 into the correct value of -0.0f and printing this value as -0.0

Comment: @DragonSpit just out of curiosity, why do you need to know if it's positive or negative zero?

Comment: It's for my unit testing, to make sure that all valid floating-point values have been covered. Currently, this negative 0 is causing some issues with one of C# standard algorithms, producing an incorrect result.

Answer (score 2):

What I'm after is converting the UInt32 pattern of 0x80000000 into the correct value of -0.0f and printing this value as -0.0 – DragonSpit

I have a bad news, apparently there's no way to get what you want:

By PETER SESTOFT:
 Some of the confusion over negative zero may stem from the
fact that the current implementations of C# print positive and negative zero in
the same way, as 0.0, and no combination of formatting parameters seems to affect
that display. Although this is probably done with the best of intentions, it is unfortunate. To reveal a negative zero, you must resort to strange-looking code like this, which
works because 1/(-0.0) = -Infinity < 0:

```
public static string DoubleToString(double d) {
 if (d == 0.0 && 1/d < 0)
 return "-0.0";
 else
 return d.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Is there somewhere we can provide feedback to Microsoft about this issue?