# Reading a float from an std::fstream returns negative zeroes

Tags: c#, c++, fstream

I'm trying to reimplement some of the methods of the C# BinaryReader class in C++, and right now I'm stuck with the [ReadSingle() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader.readsingle?view=netframework-4.8). I have the following code:

```
float BinaryReaderClass::ReadSingle() {
    float a;
    _inputStream->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a), sizeof(a));
    return a;
}
```

I tested my code using a sample file and it works most of the time, except for the fact that *sometimes* I get negative zeroes, like -0.000000, while the same function in C# returns 0.000000.

I really can't understand why.

Comment: Floating points (`float`, `double`) have separate representations of `+0.0` and `-0.0`. The resp. standard, the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) (what is commonly used in C++) has the concept of [Signed zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero). If you get `-0.0` then this is probably what is stored in the file. If you get something else in C#, maybe, it's lying (but I'm no expert of C#).

Comment: Are you _sure_ the C# version returns a different result? How do you check? When you print out `-0f` in C#, you get `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BinaryReader` doesn't do anything differently - it just interprets the in-memory data as a `float`, just like `reinterpret_cast`.

Floating point numbers have a sign. Unlike with integers, there is *two* zeroes (as with one's complement for integers) - one `-0f`, another `+0f`. However, when you call `ToString` on `-0f` in C#, you get `0` as a result. Also, `-0f == 0f`.

One way to distinguish between the two zeroes is related to how they're supposed to be used:

```
1f / 0f == PositiveInfinity
1f / -0f == NegativeInfinity
```

So try to get the float value in C# and use it as the denominator. If it's actually `-0f`, it should give you `NegativeInfinity` rather than `PositiveInfinity`.

Comment: Thanks! You were right, in C# i was always getting 0 when printing the values. I used your trick to distinguish between -0f and 0f and it works just fine, thanks again!

Comment: [How can I test for negative zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4739795/995714)